# Magento 2 get order qty items is null

Tags: magento2, event-observer, sales-order

I'm trying to get the total weight of the items in `checkout_submit_all_after`

With this code:

```
$orderItems = $order->getAllItems();

         $weight = 0.0;
         $length = 0.0;
         $width = 0.0;
         $height = 0.0;
         $dimensions = array();

          foreach ($orderItems as $item) {

              $product = $item->getProduct();
              $weight += (float) ($product->getData('weight')*$item->getQtyOrdered());

              $length += (float) $product->getData('ts_dimensions_length');
              $width += (float) $product->getData('ts_dimensions_width');
              $height += (float) $product->getData('ts_dimensions_height');   

          }

             $dimensions[] = [
                     'weigth' => $weight,
                     'length' => $length,
                     'width' => $width,
                     'height' => $height
                 ];

          $this->logger->info("Weight: ".$weight);
          $encodedData =  $this->_jsonHelper->jsonEncode($dimensions);
          $this->logger->info("Dimensiones: ".$encodedData);
```

When I print weight I get 0, I found that is because I'm getting 0 products, and another funny thing, is that my dimensions don't get summed if there are more than 1 product with same SKU. If I have 5 items with length 2, the result is 2, not 10. What I'm doing wrong here?

Please help.
Greetings!

Comment: Confirm one thing, is there a configurable product in your items?

Comment: Hello, no , this are  individual sample products for testing purpouses, they have weight, length, width, height.

Comment: Then you need to debug your script, just check with `echo $product->getData('weight')` and `echo $item->getQtyOrdered()` to check where you are getting 0. My answer would depend on that

Comment: Hello, I don't know what happened but it works now, I tried with $product->getQtyOrdered(), then change back to $item->getQtyOrdered() and it worked!

Comment: Strange, but good thing is you have resolved your issue :)